# Image sizes in detail page size is too small Magento2?

Tags: magento2, product-images, cache, product-view, small-image

I met one strange issue in Magento 2 -

Product Detail page my product image display too small.I tried using view.xml inside my theme and tried using fallback view.xml.I'm using Blank theme as parent.

view.xml

```
       <image id="product_page_main_image" type="image">
            <width>720</width>
            <height>660</height>
        </image>
        <image id="product_page_main_image_default" type="image">
            <width>720</width>
            <height>660</height>
        </image>
```

How can I set the size of the image?
Can please somebody help me.[image]

Answer (score 0):

once change `etc/view.xml` after run below command

```
php bin/magento catalog:images:resize
```

This will regenerate the new image sizes.